# How to test the livestreaming with spark AR studio

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I noticed Spark AR has a [live streaming module](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/reference/classes/livestreamingmodule/) Is there a way to simulate or test live reactions and comments without having to go live on facebook?

I would like to test if the following code actually works but I don't want to test it live on my facebook account and ask people to react and comment on the stream.

```
const LiveStreaming = require('LiveStreaming');
const Scene = require('Scene');

const matchCounterText = Scene.root.find('text1');
const comments = LiveStreaming.comments;
const matchStrings = ['cat','dog'];
const isCaseSensitive = false;

var leadingCount = 0;

comments.startMatchCounter(matchStrings,isCaseSensitive).subscribe(
function(result) {
    for (var key in result) {
        if (result[key] > leadingCount) {
            matchCounterText.text = key;
            leadingCount = result[key];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook allows you to go LIVE for a **Specific set of friends**.

Under Live Settings > See More > Specific friends > Select a friend who can help you test live reactions and comments